# How to validate xpaths in selenium over scripts

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium. I heard that in real time we will not use xpaths generated by tools..rather we will write our own. So i decided to learn writing xpaths. Can u please suggest how to practice writing xpaths and are there any tools where we can validate our written xpaths over scripts..

Answer (score 4):

you have to install firebug + firepath in mozilla firefox

[image]

it will also provide you generated xpath

[image]

You can also write the created xpath in the text field and press enter and it will validate the xpath
.//*[contains(@placeholder,'Enter your email')]

for creating xpath and locator search on google about `locator strategies in selenium`

Answer (score 1):

On writing xpaths: [a great reference website if you like reading documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

On validating xpaths: You need to run the tests and validate they're clicking on and finding the correct elements.

If there's a syntax issue with your locator, the test will fail since whatever XML parser Selenium uses in your language will throw an exception if you have a malformed xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below reference links :---------

http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium

http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/introduction-to-selenium-automation/selenium-ide/115-selenium-ide-xpath-tutorials